# Pivot fixed amount of rows to fixed amount of columns in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot-table, databricks

Imagine I have the following table:

| unique_id | column_A | column_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 12345 | ABCDEFG |
| 123 | 23456 | BCDEFGH |
| 123 | 34567 | CDEFGHI |
| 234 | 12345 | ABCDEFG |

The amount of rows per unique ID is maximum 3.
The result I want to achieve is the following

| unique_id | column_A_1 | column_A_2 | column_A_3 | column_B_1 | column_B_2 | column_B_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 12345 | 23456 | 34567 | ABCDEFG | BCDEFGH | CDEFGHI |
| 234 | 12345 |  |  | ABCDEFG |  |  |

Comment: Have a look at `PIVOT` clause in spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot.html

Comment: There's also a `pivot` pyspark function to be applied on a result of a `groupby` https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html

Comment: I know how pivot works but I can't seem to make it work with having three columns per original column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign a row_number to each record and pivot that.

Here's an example of retaining 2 values per `id` using your input dataframe.

```py
pivoted_sdf = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('rn', 
               func.row_number().over(wd.partitionBy('unique_id').orderBy(func.rand()))
               ). \
    filter(func.col('rn') <= 2). \
    groupBy('unique_id'). \
    pivot('rn', values=['1', '2']). \
    agg(func.first('col_a').alias('col_a'), 
        func.first('col_b').alias('col_b')
        )

# +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |unique_id|1_col_a|1_col_b|2_col_a|2_col_b|
# +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |      234|  12345|ABCDEFG|   null|   null|
# |      123|  34567|CDEFGHI|  23456|BCDEFGH|
# +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Notice the column names - spark added the row number as a prefix to the aggregation alias. You can rename the columns to make that as a suffix.

```py
def renameTheCol(column):
    col_split = column.split('_')
    col_split_rearr = col_split[1:] + [col_split[0]]
    new_column = '_'.join(col_split_rearr)

    return new_column

pivoted_sdf. \
    select('unique_id', 
           *[func.col(k).alias(renameTheCol(k)) for k in pivoted_sdf.columns if k != 'unique_id']
           ). \
    show()

# +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |unique_id|col_a_1|col_b_1|col_a_2|col_b_2|
# +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |      234|  12345|ABCDEFG|   null|   null|
# |      123|  23456|BCDEFGH|  34567|CDEFGHI|
# +---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know the values= parameter.